# How find one value from other row

Tags: sas

I have the following table:

[image]

I need add 1 in b column when (when the first 1 is found, then you need to add up all the 1 when this condition satisfied: c like a. Do not put 0 and 2, I only need 1):

1. find there b=1, and then
2. if c like a

This is my desired output

[image]

Comment: In output rows 15, 16 & 17, column c has values h_2_ok, h_3 & z_1_ok, these values are "like" column a in rows 11 (h_2), 15 (h_3) & 10 (z_1), respectively, so according to the logic you've given these rows should have b set to 1 because c is "like" a. What is the logic why b is not set to 1 in the output for rows 15, 16 & 17?

Comment: Because 15 row c field is 'h_2_ok' and h_2 in 11 row have value 2, and 16 row c field is 'h_3' , and 17 row c field 'z_1_ok' and 10 row is 'z_1' empty. Everything what I need capture the value 1.

Comment: I'm not understanding the logic, perhaps something is getting lost in translation.

Answer (score 0):

In the question the logic given does not match the output shown. For example in the input data, row 6 has a=y_2 and b is not set, row 7 has c with no value, this means the output should have b=0, but your output shows b=1.

As far as I can understand, the logic you want is either:

**1)** In your output you want b=1 based on the condition *if b=1 or (the value of a=the value of c in the next row)*

**or**

**2)** In your output you want b=1 based on the condition *if the value of a=the value of c in the next row* (ignoring the input value of b)

Based on these two logic scenarios, my two alternative solutions make use of the data you have shown, set up as follows:

```
data have;
  input @1 a $char3.
        @5 b
        @7 c $char3.
  ;
  datalines;
x_0 1
x_1 . x_0
x_2 . x_1
x_3 . x_2
y_1 1
y_2 . y_1
y_3 0
z_1 .
;
```

**Solution 1**

In your output if you want b=1 based on the condition *if b=1 or (the value of a=the value of c in the next row)* then try:

```
data want(drop=c2);
  merge have
        have(drop=a rename=c=c2 firstobs=2);
  
  b=(b or (a=c2)); /* the brackets are for clarity */
run;
```

This gives the output:

```
Obs a   b   c
1   x_0 1    
2   x_1 1   x_0
3   x_2 1   x_1
4   x_3 1   x_2
5   y_1 1    
6   y_2 0   y_1
7   y_3 0    
8   z_1 0
```

**Alternatively**

**Solution 2**

In your output if you want b=1 based on the condition *if the value of a=the value of c in the next row* (ignoring the input value of b) then try:

```
data want(drop=c2);
  merge have
        have(drop=a rename=c=c2 firstobs=2);
  
  b=(a=c2); /* the brackets are for clarity */
run;
```

This gives the output:

```
Obs a   b   c
1   x_0 1    
2   x_1 1   x_0
3   x_2 1   x_1
4   x_3 0   x_2
5   y_1 1    
6   y_2 0   y_1
7   y_3 0    
8   z_1 0
```